# Disconnected mailbox in exchange 2010 management console

Tags: exchange-2010

In **Exchange Management Console 2010** I deleted/removed a mailbox called client1 from the Mailbox container under Recipient Configuration.  I then re-created the mailbox with the same name.  subsequently I lost emails for a period of a week.

Now the old mailbox client1, sitting in a container called Disconnected Mailbox under Recipient Configuration.  I am assuming that the old emails are contained inside this mailbox.  I have the options to connect client1, connect to server, Export List for this mailbox.

My concern is that if I press the connect button I will loose the data in the newly created client1 mailbox.  I would like to recover all emails from the original client1 mailbox is possible.  It would be good to know the consequences of connecting the mailbox as well.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to connect this mailbox to a user account that already has a mailbox. So you won't ruin the mailbox that already exists. What you should do is create a new temporary user, attach the mailbox to that user, export the email, delete the temporary user, then import the pst into the proper account.